# How to show previewtext in JSF components?

Tags: java, jsf

Is it possible to show previewtext in JSF 1.2 components, for example in inputfields, selectmenue or in outputtext and the preview text disappears, if the user clicks into one of these components?

I saw that the attribute defaultLabel can be used in Rich faces for example? Does JSF component have a similar attribute?

Thanks & Greetz
Marwief

Comment: I have used the label attribute for example

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use **placeholders**, you can look for Primefaces [watermark](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/watermark.jsf) or RichFaces [placeholder](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=placeholder&skin=blueSky)

another way to go : take a look at passthrough with JSF2.2

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<h:inputText value="#{item.name}" p:placeholder="my item"/>
 ...
```

that will be rendered as :

```
 <input type="text" ... placeholder="my item">
```

**but beware**, this is *HTML5*